# SLURM job taking up entire node when using just one GPU

Tags: slurm

I am submitting multiple jobs to a SLURM queue. Each job uses 1 GPU. We have 4 GPUs per node. However once a job is running, it takes up the entire node, leaving 3 GPUs idle. Is there any way to avoid this, so that I can send multiple jobs to one node, using one GPU each?

My script looks like this:

```
#SLURM --gres=gpu:1
#SLURM --ntasks-per-node 1
#SLURM -p ghp-queue
myprog.exe
```

Comment: Can you try `--ntasks` instead of `--ntasks-per-node`?

Comment: Slurm does not allow that behavior. When your job is assigned a GPU-enabled node, it will keep allocated the node (and its resources) during its whole execution. You can read a related research in http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SBAC-PAD.2014.49

Comment: What is the output of `scontrol show config | grep SelectType` ?

Comment: @damienfrancois 
SelectType              = select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters    = CR_CPU

Comment: @TomdeGeus thanks for your suggestion, ntasks gives the same result

Comment: @siserte I beg to disagree. The paper you cite is 4 years old and is about remote use of GPUs. On my cluster, I can submit as many 1-GPU jobs to a multi-GPU node as there are GPUs on the node

Comment: Check that the partition is not configured with 'Shared=Exclusive'(`scontrol show partition`) and that the node is indeed configured to manage 4 GPUs (gres=...  in `scontrol show node`)

Comment: @damienfrancois thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3):

I was also unable to run multiple jobs on different GPUs. What helped was adding `OverSubscribe=FORCE` to the partition configuration in `slurm.conf`, like this:

```
PartitionName=compute Nodes=ALL ... OverSubscribe=FORCE
```

After that, I was able to run four jobs with `--gres=gpu:1`, and each one took a different GPU (a fifth job is queued, as expected).